# How to import a .profile into ipython's bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I like to run bash commands in ipython via !
however, my default path in the ipython bash (e.g. output from !$PATH) doesn't match up with $PATH from the system command line.

I've already tried

```
! . ~/.profile
```

but I get an error. Here is my output (from ipython notebook after running the above command):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// SHELL: /bin/bash
// /ifhom/myusername/.profile integrated.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/bin/sh: line 1: /ifhom/myusername/.kshout: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe its this easy:

just run:

```
ipython --profile ~/.profile
```